# Graphviz (DOT) Preview doesn't work VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygraphviz

[Screenshot of my VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IvUO.jpg)

I have tried to download the preview extension. But, it still doesn't work. Could anyone help to solve this problem? I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Seemingly the Graphviz package (containing the dot program) is not installed.  This seems to be a common problem.  Search stackoverflow for "dot not found"

Comment: The [GraphViz downloads page](https://graphviz.org/download/) is very helpful in this regard.